# Ginkgo Biloba (Autumn Gold) leaves curling up and turning pale / yellow

Tags: trees, plant-health, temperature

Here is some background information:

- The ginkgo was planted this year in spring.
- We are located in Trois-Rivières (Zone 5a) with full sun exposure
- The soil is a mixture of sand and clay.

Since mid-August, the Ginkgo Biloba has started to take on a yellowish hue and the leaves appear to be slightly curling. We have not been watering extensively due to the rainfall this summer, as we want to avoid root rot.

There are other Ginkgo trees in my neighborhood, including one troll and one regular species, which appear to be greener but more mature.

Using a moisture meter, it indicates a moderate level of moisture, but I am not able to probe more than a foot into the ground.

The leaves feel somewhat dried, leading me to suspect that the tree might be underwatered. Additionally, considering it's almost September, could the gradual change in color since mid-August be attributed to temperature variations?

Is there a reliable way to differentiate whether the tree is underwatered, overwatered, or if the color change is merely a natural response to temperature shifts?

Here are some pictures below to help !
Thank you!

[image: close up]
[image: close up2]
[image: far view]

Answer (score 3):

The faded yellow colour is what happens in autumn to the foliage,but this can happen earlier (as with your tree) if its not getting enough water; drought stress means the tree will sacrifice its foliage in an attempt to survive. Unless you have had cool, autumn-like temperatures in the last few weeks, its water shortage.

This is your tree's first year of growing in the ground - any woody plant, and particularly young trees, need a good and regular supply of water till they've got through the first 18 months or so. Once they're established,they can go longer without needing extra water, but in their first year, it's really important they don't go short of it. I'd suggest you give it a thorough watering, a good few gallons at the base of the trunk, now and every other day ongoing till its late autumn/early winter - it likely won't save the leaves, but will save the tree from dying.